# How to rename MySQL's Federated Engine SERVER name

Tags: mysql, federated

i'm trying to change a `SERVER` variable's **server name** used in the `CONNECTION` definition of a Federated Table's table properties. i manually changed it (the Server_name column) on the `mysql.servers` table. However, when creating a new federated table with the renamed `SERVER` name, an error is displayed with below message:

> 1432 - server name: **SERVER_NAME_HERE** doesn't exist!

Comment: After the manual change, did you restart MySQL?.

Comment: i didn't. am i required to? that's not really ideal specially on production servers

Comment: Was the change directly on the production server?. No test on a non-production server?.

Comment: I don't see the option in [13.1.8 ALTER SERVER Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-server.html) to modify `server_name`.